# How Do you Use Multiple Credentials in Web Request?

Tags: c#, validation, httpwebrequest, credentials

So while I am working on a web request validation method I stumbled on the credentials. My question is how to grab credentials and pass them without knowing anything about them.

Here is an idea of what I am trying to do

```
foreach(Credential c in DefaultCredentials)
{
    CredentialCache.Add(c);
}
```

then I would pass the Credentials to a web request. I dont want to have to know URI, host, port, authtype, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: I'm unclear about how credentials have anything to do with URI, port, etc.  are you asking about associating credentials with the request?

Comment: I am looking to pass multiple credentials to a web request but am unsure how to break down the credentials without knowing something about the individual credentials.

Comment: "Passing multiple credentials to a web request" doesn't really make sense.  A particular request usually only supports a single credential.  `HttpWebRequest`, for example, supports `NetworkCredential`--which is a username/password.  Maybe what you're talking about is a `CredentialCache`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx

Comment: Maybe I have it wrong but you can pass a CredentialCache to HttpWebRequest.Credentials... so I assume it will go through different Credentials to find what it needs

Comment: yes, you create a cache mapping uri to credentials, the set the web requests 'Credentials' and it picks the right credential.